# jqplot highlighter tooltip text overlaps

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, jqplot

I've given the highlighter a set width of 200px and now the text within overlaps and i can't figure out how to stop this happening. See attached.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css to the parent class

```
 white-space: normal;
```

Comment: this is because by default, if you included the distributed `jquery.jqplot.css`, `.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip` and `.jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip` have `white-space: nowrap;` set.